# remove string using Select statement in Oracle View

Tags: oracle, select, view

I have below simple View where there are several `ID_NUM` field value in which there is equal sign which i want to remove. For example one of the value is `'1AT=/F/ET'` and i want to update as `'1AT/F/ET'`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW
TR_FD
(
ID_NUM
)
AS
SELECT
    ID_NUM
FROM IS_PL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace it with an empty string:

```
select replace(id_num, '=', '') from is_pl
```